# How can I remove a layer of Silica from a rough IN718 surface?

Tags: thermodynamics, material-science, physical-chemistry, rocket-science

Our rocketry group is designing a biliquid ethaLox **Inconel 718** additively manufactured chamber.
We are looking into using **Tetraethyl orthosilicate** as a fuel additive to reduce the heat flux in our Chamber. This deposits a thin **silica** layer on the chamber wall. We need to remove the silica layer after each hotfire for several reasons. How can we do this?

Comment: The standard silicon dioxide etch is HF. Whether that attacks the Inconel (or how bad the attack would), I don’t know.

Comment: @JonCuster is correct that most of the etches are HF based (some add nitric or HCl) I've attached a paper claiming a non HF based etch:  A hydrofluoric acid-free method to dissolve and quantify silica nanoparticles in ... https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-44128-z:

Comment: @SteveSaban Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this method is out of our scope, as we dont have the technical capability.

Comment: Could you perhaps share what capabilities your lab has, and what methods you have researched so far?

Comment: @Codename47 We have shot blasting machines and any mechanical abrasion machine you would need. We can request access to chemicals through the chemistry department. Anything else we can get sponsored or pay for it.
We have researched little to nothing about removal methods.

Comment: I believe your question may be out of the scope of the Physics Stack Exchange. You might try engineering.

Comment: You could also try to scrub it or wash it in ethanol or some other solvent.